# using an Xpath wild card to get all title strings

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi I'm trying to use a wild card in my xpath expression to find the Title

So far I have this

```
x://a[@title="King"]
```

So far so good it returns the value = King

But there are 30 titles on the page and I want to loop through using an incremented variable for the offset.

So I'm trying to grab the first x://a[@title="wildcard?"] using a wildcard and I'm not having much success :(

As requested the XML

```
<a title="king" href="/king/"><div class="Igw0EIwRSHeGOV_ybXk5_4EzTm                                                                                                              ">
```

They just repeat with different class id's

I don't know a lot about XML I'm just learning xpath

Comment: How does your XML look like? (Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60368094/edit) the question and do not add it as a comment). And also add examples of what your result should look like and what not.

Comment: I have found a solution that works for me //a[@title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New to this sorry posted a comment by mistake

This is my solution to get all the title's text

```
//a[@title]
```

Is quite simple and neat and I don't have to offset and loop to get all the text for the element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only by state the attribute name:

```
//a[@title]
```

If you want to find the element with partial text of attribute's value you can use:

```
//a[contains(@title,"king")]
```

or if you know the index of the desired element you can use:

```
//a[@title][30]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply because I'm new to xpath I overthought the solution. This works for me